# How to downgrade .net maui from 11 to 5 preview?

Tags: maui

I used prism for .net maui and in current .net maui 11 preview its not really working and got reports from here https://github.com/dansiegel/Prism.Maui/issues/11 that it was working in 9th version, so how am i supposed to rollback to previous version?

Answer (score 2):

MAUI is installed alongside with Visual Studio as a workload. AFAIK there's no way to  downgrade a workload or install any version of it other than latest.

Some docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-workload-install

- Best course of action for you is to like that issue prism's repo so it will be noticeable, so they will update their NuGet to work with latest MAUI preview faster.
- Also you can manually rebuild prism's the NuGet (that's what I usually do), and create a PR if some changes are needed to build it with latest MAUI preview.

But beware that MAUI is still in preview, and breaking changes are expected with each update (so NuGet might break again). There will be preview [13](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/milestone/12) and [14](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/milestone/13), and only after them we may see a GA release (after which no breaking changes will be made).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, though i managed to make it work, though just downgraded workload via loading it from different source like : dotnet workload install android ios maccatalyst tvos macos maui wasm-tools --from-rollback-file https://aka.ms/dotnet/maui/preview.9.json --source https://aka.ms/dotnet6/nuget/index.json --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json --no-cache

Comment: Learn something new everyday! How did you find out about this? Don't see `--from-rollback-file` documented. PS: You can describe your solution in full, and post it as an answer. I'm sure it would be helpful to people

Comment: Oh, I see, it's a hidden parameter: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/cffd2db93c03697fa093fb5cef273b6cd05b88d2/src/Cli/dotnet/commands/dotnet-workload/install/WorkloadInstallCommandParser.cs#L67-L70

Comment: And looks like it's not supposed to be used unless something extreme happens: https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/28226#issuecomment-1039318632

Answer (score 1):

Set the desired dotnet sdk version in the global.json file which could look like this:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "6.0.300",
    "allowPrerelease": "false"
    "rollForward": "latestPatch"
  }
}
```

Then in the folder with the global.json run the command

```
dotnet workload restore
```